# Enter a customer number in a box, hit enter data gets populated from the sql connection

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Ideally, when I enter the customer number in a box, it populates the data. But I do not understand why that is not happening. Is it the code that is incorrect?

```
Sub Refresh()
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
Sub Refresh_SQL()
    
    'Count the current sheet's row and column
    start_row = Selection.Row
    start_col = Selection.Column
    row_count = Selection.Rows.Count
    Col_count = Selection.Columns.Count
    
    ws = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    'lock
    For i = 2 To 20
        If Cells(i, 7) = "Y" And Cells(i, 1) = ws Then
            sr = Cells(i, 3).Value
            sc = Cells(i, 4).Value
            er = Cells(i, 5).Value
            ec = Cells(i, 6).Value
            cn = Cells(i, 2).Value
            GoTo cn_lock
        End If
    Next i
        
    
    'unlock
    For i = 2 To 20
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = CStr(ws) Then
            cn = Cells(i, 2).Value
            'count row from start to end
            Cells(i, 3).Value = start_row
            Cells(i, 4).Value = start_col
            Cells(i, 5).Value = (start_row + row_count - 1)
            Cells(i, 6).Value = (start_col + Col_count - 1)
            
        End If
    Next i
    
    sql = ""
    Sheets(ws).Select
    For Each CL In Range(Cells(start_row, start_col), Cells((start_row + row_count - 1), (start_col + Col_count - 1)))
            sql = sql & " " & CL.Text
    Next CL
    GoTo cn_unlock
    
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
cn_lock:
    sql = ""
    Sheets(ws).Select

    For Each CL In Range(Cells(sr, sc), Cells(er, ec))

        sql = sql & " " & CL.Text
    Next CL
    
    
    
    'MsgBox Sql
cn_unlock:
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections(cn).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(cn).OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = sql
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections(cn).Refresh
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0



    Sheets(ws).Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
Sub RefreshAll()

    'Grab Whs and Item
    Sheets("Pricing").Select
 

    Sheets("Fence").Select
    Range("M11").Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Ideally, when I enter the customer number in a box, it populates the data. But I do not understand why that is not happening. Is it the code that is incorrect?

Comment: You need a [worksheet_change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) in the sheet object code. Right now it's just an ordinary sub that runs when you click on run macro.